# can php-saml lib from onelogin act as an IDP?

Tags: php, saml-2.0, simplesamlphp, onelogin

My application needs to provide IDP like service using which I like to generate a saml response to the registered SP. So that users of my application can login to the registered SP's applications. But I think php-saml(provided by OneLogin) lib is SP side library which would process IdP response. Can I use it to generate saml response (like an IdP) so that SP can allow users to login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OneLogin php-saml library is the SP side, only.  However, there is another tool available, SimpleSAMLphp, that can do the IdP side:

https://simplesamlphp.org/